# Custom Page Form and db insertion magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, forms, install-script

I have created a custom Form and try to store details in databse. but the product url field and image url is not saved in db.

**app/code/Dyode/Pricebeat/Controller/User/Post.php**

```
<?php
 namespace Dyode\Pricebeat\Controller\User;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
 use Dyode\Pricebeat\Model\FormFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
 use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request;

 class Post extends Action
  {
protected $_modelFormFactory;
protected $resultPageFactory;
protected $_sessionManager;


public function __construct(
  Context $context,
  FormFactory $modelFormFactory,
  PageFactory $pageFactory,
  SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager)
{
    $this->resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->_modelFormFactory = $modelFormFactory;
    $this->_sessionManager = $sessionManager;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $this->validatedParams();
    $this->getFormData();
    echo "hello from the controller";
    exit();
}

private function validatedParams()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if (trim($request->getParam('first_name')) === '') {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('First Name is missing'));
    }

    if (trim($request->getParam('last_name')) === '') {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('Last Name is missing'));
    }

    if (false === \strpos($request->getParam('email'), '@')) {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('Invalid email address'));
    }
    if (trim($request->getParam('phonenumber')) === '') {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('Phone Number is missing'));
    }
    if (trim($request->getParam('account_number')) === '') {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('Account Number is missing'));
    }
    if (trim($request->getParam('invoice_number')) === '') {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('Invoice Number is missing'));
    }
    if (trim($request->getParam('product_url')) === '') {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('product url Number is missing'));
    }
    if (trim($request->getParam('product_image_url')) !== '') {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('image is missing'));
    }

    //Add your more validations here
    return $request->getParams();
}
private function getFormData()
{

   $resultRedirect     = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
   $FormModel          = $this->_modelFormFactory->create();
   $data               = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
   $date               = date('Y-m-d h:i:sa');

   $FormModel->setData('first_name', $data['first_name']);
   $FormModel->setData('last_name', $data['last_name']);
   $FormModel->setData('email', $data['email']);
   $FormModel->setData('phonenumber', $data['phonenumber']);
   $FormModel->setData('account_number', $data['account_number']);
   $FormModel->setData('invoice_number', $data['invoice_number']);
   $FormModel->setData('product_url', $data['product_url']);
   $FormModel->setData('product_image_url', $data['product_url']);


   $FormModel->setData('created_date', $date);
   $FormModel->setData('status', $data['status']);

   $FormModel->save();

   $this->_redirect('blog/index');
   $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The data has been saved.'));
}
}
```

**app/code/Dyode/Pricebeat/view/frontend/templates/pricebeat.phtml**

```
<div class="wk-mp-design">
<fieldset class="fieldset info wk-mp-fieldset">
    <legend class="legend">
        <span><?php echo __('Pricebeat') ?></span>
    </legend>
    <form action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('pricebeat/user/post', ['_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()]) ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="quote-request" data-form="quote-request" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
        <div class="field required">
            <label class="label"><?php echo __('First Name') ?>:</label>
            <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" title="First Name" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field required">
            <label class="label"><?php echo __('Last Name') ?>:</label>
            <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" title="Last Name" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field required">
            <label class="label"><?php echo __('Email Address') ?>:</label>
            <div class="control">
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" title="Email Address" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field required">
            <label class="label"><?php echo __('Phone Number') ?>:</label>
            <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" title="Phone Number" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-number':true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field required">
            <label class="label"><?php echo __('Account Number') ?>:</label>
            <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" id="account_number" name="account_number" title="Account Number" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-number':true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field required">
            <label class="label"><?php echo __('Invoice/Order Number') ?>:</label>
            <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" id="invoice_number" name="invoice_number" title="Invoice Number" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-number':true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
            <label class="label"><?php echo __('Product Url') ?>:</label>
            <div class="control">
            <input type="text" id="product_url" name="product_url" title="Product Url" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
            <?php echo __("Product image") ?>
            <div class="control">
                    <input type="file" id="product_image_url" name="product_image_url"  title="product_image_url" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        <button class="button wk-mp-btn" title="<?php echo __('Submit') ?>" type="submit" id="submit-btn">
            <span><span><?php echo __('Submit') ?></span></span>
        </button>
    </form>
</fieldset>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#quote-request": {
        "validation": {}
    }
}
</script>
```

**app/code/Dyode/Pricebeat/Setup/InstallSchema.php**

```
<?php

 namespace Dyode\Pricebeat\Setup;

 class InstallSchema implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface
  {
  /**
   * install tables
   *
   * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup
   * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context
   * @return void
   * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
   */
public function install(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();
    if (!$installer->tableExists('dyode_pricebeat_form')) {
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('dyode_pricebeat_form')
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'form_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            [
                'identity' => true,
                'nullable' => false,
                'primary'  => true,
                'unsigned' => true,
            ],
            'Form ID'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'first_name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable => false'],
            'First Name'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'last_name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [],
            'Last Name'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'email',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [],
            'Email'
            )
        ->addColumn(
            'phonenumber',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            255,
            [],
            'Phone Number'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'account_number',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            255,
            [],
            'Account Number'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'invoice_number',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            255,
            [],
            'Invoice Number'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'product_url',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            1,
            ['nullable => false'],
            'Product Url'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'product_image_url',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            1,
            ['nullable => false'],
            'Product Image Url'
        )

        // ->addColumn(
        //     'imagethumbnail',
        //     \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        //     255,
        //     [],
        //     'Image Thumbnail'
        // )
        // ->addColumn(
        //     'show_in_frontend',
        //     \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        //     1,
        //     ['nullable => false'],
        //     'form Show in Frontend'
        // )
        ->addColumn(
            'status',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            1,
            ['nullable => false'],
            'form Status'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'created_at',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            [],
            ' Created At'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'updated_at',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            [],
            ' Updated At'
        )
        ->setComment('Form Table');
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        $installer->getConnection()->addIndex(
            $installer->getTable('dyode_pricebeat_form'),
            $setup->getIdxName(
                $installer->getTable('dyode_pricebeat_form'),
                ['first_name','last_name','email','phonenumber','account_number','product_url','product_image_url'],
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
            ),
            ['first_name','last_name','email','phonenumber','account_number','product_url','product_image_url'],
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
        );
    }
    $installer->endSetup();
}
}
```

Comment: have got any error at system and exception log?

Comment: no error at system

Comment: Please check magento system.log and exception.log file>

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in

```
$FormModel->setData('product_image_url', $data['product_url']);
```

Change that to:

```
$FormModel->setData('product_image_url', $data['product_image_url']);
```

Plus, it's not so easy to upload a file and store the URL. You'll need to save the file and extract the filename, see http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php.